# Phpspreadsheet - Memory Exhausted

Tags: php, out-of-memory, phpspreadsheet

When I export large spreasheet I am getting this fatal error:

> phpspreadsheet allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added the below code in the export to excel function
`ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');`. This solved the memory exhausted issue.